# SHA512 hash in crypto++ library throws exception

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, crypto++, sha512

I built crypto++ 8.4 in visual studio 2010 and made some test code.
It works fine in 'Win32|Debug', but in 'Win32|Release' hash.CalculateDigest throws an exception.

```
    string source = "I am a programmer.";

    CryptoPP::SHA512 hash;
    CryptoPP::byte digest[CryptoPP::SHA512::DIGESTSIZE];            
    hash.CalculateDigest(digest, (const CryptoPP::byte*)source.c_str(), source.length());

    string result;  
    CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;

    encoder.Attach(new CryptoPP::StringSink(result));
    encoder.Put(digest, sizeof(digest));
```

The location where the exception occurs is as follows. (sha.cpp)
[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please find "call stack" window and copy paste crashed thread call stack entries. Find entry which points to your code (closest to tip) and show where it point in code provided.

Comment: Please also provide more details about your processor (i.e. which architecture and if it supports SSE2), and how you obtained crypto++ 8.4 (i.e. did you compile it yourself, if so, what flags did you use, if not, where did you obtain the binaries from).

Comment: Also, related entry in the crypt++ issue tracker: https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/1004

Comment: Does it even use SSE2 in VS2010 32 bit debug builds? If I recall correctly, VS2010 32 bit compiler still emitted instructions for the Intel FPU. Maybe it is just taking different code paths in your debug and release builds? A quick test that you can maybe do is to pass /arch:sse2 flag to the debug buiild and see it hits the same problem. In any case a call stack is a absolutely required for debugging this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found definite case of an exception.
If 'hash' is declared as a pointer rather than a local variable, no exception is raised.

```
CryptoPP::SHA512 * hash = new CryptoPP::SHA512;
```

I don't know why this is happening, but in the case of SHA512, I doubt that there is a memory management problem in cryptopp in VS 2010.